# Replacing window.localStorage implementation for Facebook Instant Games

Tags: javascript, facebook, local-storage, facebook-instant-games

I am preparing a game for publishing at Facebook Instant Games.

My game uses Pixi.js and jQuery UI - and saves some user settings like "color theme" and "sound volume" in window.localStorage:

[image: game screenshot]

However when trying to access it from my Instant Game, I get the error:

> DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

I guess the root cause is that Facebook Instant games run in an iframe.

However, I have already published [my game](https://yandex.com/games/play/147407) at the Yandex Games platform and there they offer [a replacement for localStorage](https://yandex.ru/dev/games/doc/dg/sdk/sdk-player.html) by running the following code:

```
ysdk.getStorage()
    .then(safeStorage => Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', 
        { get: () => safeStorage }))
    .then(() => {
       localStorage.setItem('key', 'safe storage is working');
       console.log(localStorage.getItem('key'))
    });
```

So I wonder if the same trick is possible by using `FBInstant.player.setDataAsync()` and `FBInstant.player.getDataAsync()` found in the [Instant Games SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/sdk/fbinstant7.0)?

I have tried:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', 
    { get: () => { 
    getItem: { FBInstant.player.getDataAsync() }, 
    setItem: { FBInstant.player.setDataAsync() } } }));
```

but that is of course not working... I am not even sure, how to deal with Facebook's async functions here.

Comment: getItem and setItem are not async function. So you can't replace them with async functions. You would have to make a wrapper that is async that you use. That sometimes uses localstorage and sometimes uses FBInstant.player. And then you will have to update everything to call your wrapper instead of localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to keep the syntax

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', 
{ getItem: key => FBInstant.player.getDataAsync(...) , 
  setItem: (key,str) => FBInstant.player.setDataAsync(...)
})
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/sdk/fbinstant6.1/

Comment: Would that work `getItem: key => { var data = await FBInstant.player.getDataAsync([key]); return data[key]; }`?

Comment: Possibly. I have never used FB api

Comment: getItem and setItem are not async function. So you can't replace them with async functions.